# Slider does not work in the jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, flexslider

I want to use 2 jQuery Flexsliders in the jQuery tabs. The slider on the tab 1 works fine, but it does not work in the tab 2.

Here is the full demo of the code on JSFiddle:

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/vH5DT/

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tabvanilla').tabs({
        hide: "heightFade",
        show: "heightFade",
        collapsible: true
    });

    $('#flexslider1').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: true,
        controlsContainer: ".flex-container1",
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: true
    });

    $('#flexslider2').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: true,
        controlsContainer: ".flex-container2",
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: true
    });

    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabvanilla">
    <ul class="tabnav">
      <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab1" class="cf">
      <div id="flexslider1" class="flexslider">

        <ul class="slides">
          <li><img src="" /></li>
          <li><img src="" /></li>
          <li><img src="" /></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="flex-container1"></div>

    </div><!-- div#tab1 -->

  <div id="tab2">
       <div id="flexslider2" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li><img src="" /></li>
            <li><img src="" /></li>
            <li><img src="" /></li>
         </ul>

        <div class="flex-container2"></div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- div#tab2 -->
  </div><!-- div#tabvanilla -->
```

Comment: one of the jquery files is setting the style of your second tab contents "LI" to this: width: 0px; float: left; display: block; that width:0 is "hiding" the contents

Comment: @Andres, Yes i think too that hidden property has problem with the slider. Could you please suggest how to I can fix it?

Comment: Still also looking for an answer

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple possible approaches to the problem that the slider script can't act on hidden elements--either re-initialize the slider script on each tab click, or use

```
position: absolute;
left: -999em;
```

and then

```
left: auto;
```

rather than

```
display: none;
```

for the tabs.

Comment: I kind of get this do you place this in the .tabs function? Or more in the css

Comment: This is CSS. Put it where it will load after other Bootstrap CSS so it takes precedence.

Comment: would this be in the: .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel?

Comment: That sounds correct. Look for the elements Bootstrap hides when you switch tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand... I just see tab1/tab2 gets aria hidden="true or false with the jquery ui..what bootstrap are you referring..do you mean the flex css that is in the fiddle?

Comment: I apologize--I'm confusing two different questions. Anyway, find out what elements are being hidden in the tabs and move them offscreen instead. This is fairly fundamental CSS sleuthing.

Comment: the only way to do this is by the id: #tab1 and #tab2...but this would not work if i place more tabs (cms thinking)...I'll keep at it...

Comment: Your tabs should have a class in addition to unique IDs that you can use for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35291/discussion-between-riskbreaker-and-isherwood)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to init your flexslider when visible (on tab change)

I think you can do something like this :

```
$('#tabvanilla').tabs({
    hide: "heightFade",
    show: "heightFade",
    collapsible: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        switch (ui.index) {
            case 0:
                // nothing to do since this is selected by default on page load
                break;
            case 1:
                $('#flexslider2').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    slideshow: true,
                    controlsContainer: ".flex-container2",
                    directionNav: true,
                    controlNav: true
                });
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to contribute with another solution that works fine for me.
I diving into the code and I use firebug to discover that Andres is right. The problem is because all hiddens

at the beginning has their width setted to 0.
When I opened firebug everything works fine, hiddens

take the right width.
Well, I do that:
I putted this piece of code after the click event and the transition:

```
fixWidth = $next_slide.css('width'); // I take the width of the new active slide
$flexslide_tab = $next_slide.find('.flexslider'); // Localize flexslider inside active tab
$ul = $flexslide_tab.find('.slides'); // Localize <li> container
$lis = $ul.find('li'); // Get all <li> elements
$lis.each(function(i,elem) {
    $(this).css('width',fixWidth); // I adjust every <li> width from the new slide
});
```

I hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be help for you..

Add this script to the first tab content page

```
$(window).load(function () {
    initFlexSliders();
});


function initFlexSliders() {
        $('#carousel').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 100,
            itemMargin: 5,
            asNavFor: '#slider'
        });

        $('#slider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            sync: "#carousel",
            start: function (slider) {
                $('body').removeClass('loading');
            }
        });

    $('#carousel-1').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 100,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider-1'
    });

    $('#slider-1').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: "#carousel-1",
        start: function (slider) {
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
}
```

for other tabs insert this at the bottom of the content.

```
initFlexSliders();
```