# Add flexslider(s) on Jquery UI tabs - making them work

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui, flexslider

I have a flexslider working on the first Jquery UI tab, but when I place on the second one its a nogo....anyone know what else you have to add to make this function work? I included a ***Jfiddle*** of the one thats not working:

```
$('#slider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false
            });

$('#slider2').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false
            });
```

[**JFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sLww)

That link had answers but nothing proof working.... I saw Advanced Slider has this method to make it work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(".ui-tabs").tabs({ select: function (event, ui) {
          if ($(ui.panel).find('.advanced-slider').length) {
               var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if ($(ui.panel).css('display') == 'block') {
                         $('.advanced-slider').advancedSlider().doSliderLayout();
                         clearInterval(interval);
                    }
               }, 100);
          }
     }});
});
</script>
```

From this link:

**[LINK](http://support.bqworks.com/entries/25056822-Multiple-sliders-on-jQuery-tabs)**

So I'm wondering if how I would implement this to flexslider.

Comment: Many similar questions on SO. You have to initialize each slider after the tab is selected because those hidden elements have no size, so the slider can't do the math on them.

Comment: yeah before I asked this, I'd try to look for something similar....no luck yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slider does not work in the jQuery Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202147/slider-does-not-work-in-the-jquery-tabs)

Comment: Thanks @isherwood I added a note...need to figure if that is an edit to the jquery or the css

Comment: I found a way!! it was just CSS

Comment: Well done. How about posting the answer as an answer or closing the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way!

@isherwood thanks your way was close but it did help me figure to set the ui tabs css:

```
.ui-tabs__panel {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:0;
    top: 5em;
    left: -9999em
}

.ui-tabs__panel--active {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:1;
    left: 0;
}
```