# Jquery SlideToggle divs to slide (animate) up

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I want to know how can you make this perfect example slide up instead of pushing the 'navs' down

http://jsfiddle.net/NPRfM/3/

...right now, it reveals from top to bottom (pushes the menu down)...I want the reverse..meaning boxes slide up to reveal and pushes navs up - clicking on one pushes the menu up to reveal the boxes.

That fiddle is on the mark on what I want to do only I want it slide up to reveal

**I tried something like this but no go**

```
.animate({scrollTop: $('.dropdown').offset().top}, 250);
```

do I have to also use some css positioning to have it offset? ...still learning the ropes on jquery

**UPDATE****

HERE is what i want it to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/WFxLJ/1169/

....The only issue is, I cant figure a way to do it like the first jfiddle...where it kind of has 2 functions.

-==click div 1===slides up -reveals content of div 1 (in same section 2)

====click div 2 after ======shows content of div 2 (in same section of 1)

=====click div 2 again=======slides down the box to hide section

and vice -versa

Hope I make sense.

**Update 2****

I almost got it! Check the jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b7C2d/315/

So the only thing left is the menu (black) needs to push up so it looks like it reveals...I assume this is just CSS is it the fixed positioning..(changing it to relative just messes it)?

I have found a site that does this:

[Dean](http://www.deancare.com/)

But their code is more complicated then it should be.... plus it looks like from 2001 (no way I am going to try to mess with this code)..but anyways thats what i want to do.

**Update 3****

This is the closest I can get it but it is acting like its missing a few screws :(

http://jsfiddle.net/b7C2d/347/

Comment: @Riksbreaker i am not getting your problem what you want.

Comment: @Dh... I added another jfiddle and update

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why I got a negative on this

Comment: Not sure, but I up voted it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like So?

**UPDATED: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emtvr/10/)**

```
/* CREATED BY SHIVAM BHALLA */

(function($) {
    $('body').addClass('js');

    var $toggler = $('#toggler'),
        $wrapper = $toggler.find('.wrapper'),
        $pager = $toggler.find('.pager'),
        $content = $toggler.find('.content');

    $toggler.css('height', $content.height() + $pager.height());
    $wrapper.css('top', $content.height());
    $content.hide();

    $pager.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $target =  $( $(this).attr('href') ),
            $count = 0;

        if ($count === 0) {
            $wrapper.animate({'top' : 0});
            $count = 1;
            $this.addClass('selected');
        } 
        if ($target.hasClass('active')) {
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $wrapper.animate({'top' : $content.height()}, function() {
                $target.hide().removeClass('active');
            });
        } else {
            $wrapper.find('.active').slideUp().removeClass('active');
            $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');
        }       

        e.preventDefault();            
    });



})(jQuery);
```

P.S: New js, html & css. Also looks good with Javascript disabled.

Comment: OMG so close..yes but how can you close it if you click on a section the second time...seem like yours only opens once and stays open..yours is so clean!

Comment: Shivan you are just a one man genius! Excellent work wow so little code thank you! All credits to you!

Comment: is it possible to give the a (headings) active classes also? I tried adding toggleClass of active but that just gives it display none to the heading @Shivam

Comment: I figured it out... but man your so quick maybe you can help me figure my other SO issue heh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154105/add-flexsliders-on-jquery-ui-tabs-making-them-work

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS :

```
#panels {
    height: 90px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And change `.info-panel` to this :

```
.info-panel { 
    display: none; 
    width: 300px; 
    padding: 50px 20px 20px 20px; 
    position: absolute; 
}
```

**[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7C2d/342/)**

Comment: Thanks. But the problem still lies..it slides underneath the gray bg.. I want it to start inside the gray bg and push the black nav up and down

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#bottom) with some options tacked on.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/KuN5p/1/)**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#tabs").tabs({
         collapsible: true,
         active: false,
         fx: {
             height: 'toggle',
             duration: 'slow'
         }
     });

     // fix the classes
     $(".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav, .tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav > *")
         .removeClass("ui-corner-all ui-corner-top")
         .addClass("ui-corner-bottom");
     // move the nav to the bottom
     $(".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav").appendTo(".tabs-bottom");

 });
```

Comment: Thanks man that looks great... the problem is like @Brewal I want the black nav to be pushed up and down...so its like a reveal panel...like the Dean site I posted

Comment: I gave the answer to Shivam since I was looking for the animate effect but thanks!

Comment: @Riskbreaker this solution animates as well